# Is there a better way to use SEARCH in two-dimensional arrays of COBOL?

Tags: arrays, search, cobol

The Cobol's SEARCH keyword can be used to search one dimensional arrays indexed.

But I think this SEARCH is having some disadvantages when used for searching 2-d arrays.
We can search using PERFORM loop also but is there a better way of utilizing SEARCH for 2-d arrays. Which one do you propose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What disadvantages does it have? If your arrays are sorted you can use SEARCH ALL instead (it is using the binary search instead of a serial one). Either way, using the search statement is probably more consise than writing several nested perform loops.

Also [take a look here](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/6.2.32.2?SHELF=igy3sh33&DT=20060329140556).